# Pass different classes using Arraylist from one activity to another

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm using the class Tests as the base class, the I created three more classes, Test1, Test2, Test3, they extends Tests class, then I have one more class, States which has an Arraylist.

States is used to gather a bunch of info including a list with the tests I want to perform, so I use the Arraylist and the method "add" to add test1, test2, or test3 to the list, then I want to send this State object to the activity B. I've implemented the parcelable interface on classes Test1, Test2, Test3 and States but I'm getting the next exception:

Unmarshalling unknown type code 6357090 at offset 300

Please, can suggest any way to achieve this, It's important to gather the tests on the arraylist, i think there lies the problem, thanks.

Comment: What does your Test class extend?

Comment: Does `Tests` implement parcelable as well?

Comment: it does not extend from other class except i suppose the object class of java

Comment: it implements the parcelable but only with two simple items, a string and an int, the classes Test1, test2 and test3 implement parcelable too with a huge but different kind of data.

Comment: Does the parcelable implementation in `Test1` include `super`? Eg,  `protected Test1(Parcel in) { super(in); }`

Comment: As Test1 extends from Tests class I use a getter into test1 to get the value of the string and the int, then I put them into the parce, so i'm not using the super.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, this is too long for a comment, so I posted as an answer

Since Test1 extends Tests, Tests should haveit's own Parcelable implementation.
This implementation is the called by all its 'child' classes by using `super`. For example (this is what I use in my apps):

Tests class

```
public class Tests implements Parcelable {
    private int Id;
    private String Name;

    // parcelable
    protected Tests(Parcel in) {
      Id = in.readInt();
      Name = in.readString();
  }

  public static final Creator<Tests> CREATOR = new Creator<Tests>() {
    @Override
    public Tests createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Tests(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Tests[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Tests[size];
    }
  };

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(Id);
    dest.writeString(Name);
  }
}
```

Test1 class

```
public class Test1 extends Tests implements Parcelable {

  private int Score;

  // parcelable
  protected Test1(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    Score = in.readInt();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeInt(Score);
  }

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  public static final Creator<Test1> CREATOR = new Creator<Test1>() {
    @Override
    public Test1 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Test1(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Test1[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Test1[size];
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: How would you implement the States class and its parcelable interface, this class must have an Arraylist that can contain either Test1, Test2, or Test3. I put this class into an intent and send the intent to another class, there, I get the parcelable arraylist and check each object with is instance of, but I'm getting that error.

Comment: These methods. 
Parcel.createTypedArrayList(Tests.CREATOR). Parcel.writeTypedList(Tests).

Comment: I've tried dest.writeList() and dest.writeTypedList() but neither of them works, that is the real problem.